# Adaptive or Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design, mobile-website, adaptive-design

I am planning on making a website but now I am considering using adaptive or responsive for mobile experience. personally, I never create adaptive design before. I think that will possibly different layout and content to show, on my previous experience responsive layout is "hiding" the element to not show on some device size like bootstrap using  "hidden-xs" or "visible-xs", but using that way actually Web Page also need to get data from server and maybe loop or process whatever function but in the end just only for desktop and hidden for mobile.
is it best practice? or any other better way or best practice to solve this?

Comment: This type of question is out of scope for SO. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree with ZimSystem, but the way you have described bootstrap, while true, isn't the only way to use bootstrap. You can resize elements for different screens, therefore, making the entire site function as desired on any device. If you want to discuss let me know.

Comment: @Alex, Actually it is not only for size problem but sometimes we need to display different layout, shape or data just for specific screen size. in previous way I just hide it but i realize that actually it was generated and processed

Comment: @ZimSystem, Thanks for advice, i will read about "How do I ask a good question?"